# Pass model subset on button click Mvc Core

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

i am looking to pass through a class from a model subset on button click, this is because i have a model that contains multiple lists of classes that correspond to different datatable. I want to be able to pass one of the classes to a controller on button click or form submit. Below is what i have am aiming for.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PersonForm.Where(x => x.PersonType == Utils.PersonTypeEnum.PurchaseType.Owner))
                                        {
                                            <tr>
                                                <th scope="row">@item.Id</th>
                                                <td>@(item.PersonModel.Id)</td>
                                                <td>@(item.PersonModel.Name)</td>
                                                <td>Normal</td>
                                                <td>@($"{item.PersonModel.DOB}")</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <button class="btn-success btn " onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AcceptPersonJob", "PersonArea",item.PersonModel)'">Accept</button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        }
```

Comment: So, what's the problem now, can you achieve your goal by the above codes?

Comment: No this passes the class as a giant querysting that gives me a 405 error, i was wondering if there is a way of doing this by posting as a form

Answer (score 0):

The 405 error mainly casused by the Http method. The button send a `get` request, you can put a `[HttpGet]` attribute on your action. If this is not the case, please show us your controller action and your model.